# MBR to GPT conversion messed up Linux partitions

Tags: gparted, partitioning

I recently had to convert the drive all the Linux partitions were in to GPT from AOMEI in Windows. First thing I did was go to GParted and check whether everything was fine and it was totally not

Although Linux still boots, it boots painfully slow, it used to be much faster. And looking at gparted, it seems partition names and flags are all messed up, mount points all seem to be fine however, I was hopping someone here who is an expert with Ubuntu can tell me what I need to change so I don't face any problems in the future because of improperly configured Linux partitions

Here is a screenshot of gparted:
[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzRhA.png)

Spot anything wrong? From what I can definitely tell, the swap partition goes inactive after I reboot, probably the reason behind slow boots?

Thank you

Comment: Did an UUID get changed? check that particularly swap but all mounted partitions per fstab match UUIDs per `lsblk -e7 -f` (excludes loop devices) or `sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list`.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you are asking me to check whether partition UUIDs match and I can display them using `lsblk -e7 -f` but where I am supposed to find the old UUIDs Linux expects? A config file? or some other command?

Comment: Also may I add that when I'm in gparted through a terminal Window and I try to change flags on one of those partitions it gives me a 'The journal is not empty' error and in the terminal window it says 'Bad block list header checksum' so I'm guessing that something doesn't match indeed. I just don't know what

Comment: Compare UUIDs you have to UUIDs in /etc/fstab. But now if you also have file corruption, you may need to run fsck on all ext4 partitions. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143583/mbr-to-gpt-conversion-messed-up-linux-partitions?noredirect=1#comment1898084_1143583 What flags are you trying to change? Normally only flag is boot/esp on FAT32 ESP - efi system partition if UEFI boot. Or if BIOS boot on gpt drive, an unformatted bios_grub partition.